# Persisting array data locally in AngularJS app to be shared between two applications

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have some array data `var queries = [];` that I want to be persisted and shared between two AngularJS application. 2 applications meaning one for the front end and second for the admin end. Both the ends make the whole page load for when they are loaded.

I tried using the following code for sharing the data but it doesn't seem to work:

```
.factory('QueryService', function() {
        var queries = [];
        var factory = {};
        //..
    factory.addQuery = function(query) {
          queries.push(query);
        localStorage.setItem('queries', JSON.stringify(queries));
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('queries')));
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('queries'));
    };
    //..
    return factory;
}
```

I only get the last element added to the `queries` array with the above code.

I also tried the following using the [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) but I still get the same result.

```
.factory('QueryService', ['localStorageService', function(localStorageService) {
        var queries = [];
        var factory = {};
        //..
    factory.addQuery = function(query) {
          queries.push(query);
        localStorageService.set('queries', queries);
        console.log(localStorageService.get(('queries')));
        return localStorageService.get(('queries'));
    };
    //..
    return factory;
}
```

I need the array `queries` data to be available in the front end app and also in the admin end.

Could somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the factory to setup private variables for the specific factory that you can then set and fetch the value of that private variable.

You could create another method to clear the queries variable too if necessary.

```
    .factory('QueryService', function () {
        var queries = [];
        var factory = {};

        return {
            addQuery : function (query) {
                queries.push(query);
                localStorage.setItem('queries', JSON.stringify(queries));
                console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('queries')));
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('queries'));
            },
            fetchQuery : function ( ) {
                return localStorage.getItem('queries');
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: When the admin end is loaded, which causes the whole page to get loaded, would the `queries` array not lose all the data this way? Would we not need a `localStorage` for persisting it locally?

Comment: If you're talking between two apps, you're going to need some type of middleware to assist in the communication between apps (like websockets, etc.) -- localStorage IMO is a flimsy way to persist data between two apps.

Comment: I misread the original post -- as I was assuming the front/back end are both loading the same factory.

Comment: Yes Chris, both the ends are loading the same factory. That was how I thought I could share the data using `localStorage`. As I thought `localStorage` did not mind sharing data in different tabs.

Comment: I've worked on an app with an old employer in which we had to receive data from one app, add to it, and pass it on to another app. You need to use sockets.io or something similiar to get it done. localStorage will work but you don't want to rely on it IMO.

You can use the example I provided, as it should allow the queries array to persist for each "addQuery" and then instead of returning the queries array from fetchQuery, just have to fetch from localStorage.

Comment: Its not working even the way you've updated it in your answer, that is as a factory but not a service, like I did in my post, using `localStorage`. I was using `localStorage` as I was building a prototype but not the actual app. When building an actual app, will be using a database. What could be the reason behind why its not working with `localStorage`?

Comment: No, I am just getting the last element being added to the `queries` array.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
// save to localStorage
localStorage.myData = angular.toJson(data);


// retrieve from localStorage
var data = angular.fromJson(localStorage.myData);
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Did you try `console.log`ging the value, what does it say?

Comment: Yes, I got the `queries` array retrieved from the `localStorage` using `console.log(angular.fromJson(localStorage.queries));`, both the times it showed only the last element added to the `queries` array.

Comment: You probably need to adjust the way you're adding individual items to your final array. If nothing else, I suggested the Angular way of using `localStorage` (and also `sessionStorage`) which you should stick to.

Comment: I've got the code for how I adding the newly added elements to the `queries` array. Could you tell me what other way could make it work. Also, if you could tell me the angular way of using `localStorage`. Thanks.